# On testing two fully expanded character strings for equality

Tags: macros, conditionals, expansion

I know three macros that test two fully expanded character strings for equality:

1. `\ifthenelse{\equal{<op1>}{<op2>}}{<true>}{<false>}` ([`ifthen`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xifthen/xifthen.pdf) package)
2. `\IfStrEq{<op1>}{<op2>}{<true>}{<false>}` ([`xstring`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) package)
3. `\ifstr{<op1>}{<op2>}{<true>}{<false>}` ([`scrbase`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) package)

Interestingly, they share one drawback: They are fragile, which means that

- we have to `\protect` them in moving arguments (e.g. in the argument of `\section`).
- they don’t properly work in the context of PDF string expansion (e.g. for PDF outlines) as implemented by the [`hyperref`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) package.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\juhu}{%
  juhu%
}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \IfStrEq{#1}{juhu}{Juhu!}{Oje!}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\juhu}}
%% \section{\protect\test{\juhu}}

\end{document}
```

Hence my question: Is it possible to implement an equality test that fully expands its operands, but removes the restrictions listed above?

Comment: I think the answer is "no"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This was my guess. But, there’s always hope ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\juhu}{juhu}
\newcommand*{\nojuhu}{nojuhu}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{juhu}=\z@ Juhu!\else Oje!\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\juhu}}

\section{\test{\nojuhu}}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\pdf@strcmp` from `pdftexcmds` is for allowing the test also with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. With `pdflatex` it suffices to use `\pdfstrcmp`.

`\pdf@strcmp{A}{B}` returns 0 if the strings are, after full expansion to unexpandable tokens, equal; -1 if `A` precedes `B` in lexicographic order (based on ASCII code of the final detokenized list) and 1 if `A` follows `B`.

(Of course, e-TeX is required, so no Knuth TeX.)

Comment: Résumé: Works! :-) Based on the `\pdfstrcmp` primitive (pdfTeX), the `\strcmp` primitive (XeTeX) and a Lua function (LuaTeX), respectively. Active and `inputenc` characters are handled reliably, comparison is catcode-agnostic. But, as stated, you need the ε-TeX extensions.

Comment: I assume by Knuth TeX you mean Plain-TeX, but what exactly does "no Knuth TeX" mean?

Comment: @GeoffPointer “Knuth TeX” is “TeX the program” without the e-TeX extensions.

Answer (score 16):

This doesn't have *those* restrictions, but it has others. Buyer beware:-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\juhu}{%
  juhu%
}

\makeatletter

\def\test#1{%
   \expandafter\xtest\romannumeral`\Q#1\muskipdef\valign juhu\muskipdef\voffset{yes}{no}%
}

\def\xtest#1#2#3#4#5{\xxtest}

\def\xxtest#1#2\valign#3#4\voffset{%
  \ifx\muskipdef#1%
    \ifx\muskipdef#3%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx\muskipdef#3%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
      \xiterate{#2}{#4}%
    \fi
  \fi}


\def\xiterate#1#2\fi\fi{\fi\fi\expandafter\xtest\romannumeral`\Q#1\valign#2\voffset}

\typeout{[[\test{\juhu}]]}
\typeout{[[\test{x\juhu}]]}
\typeout{[[\test{\juhu\empty}]]}


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\juhu}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Résumé: Works! :-) Based on `\romannumeral`. Active characters are handled reliably, comparison is catcode-agnostic. But, `inputenc` characters are not handled.

Comment: inputenc should be OK, what example were you trying?

Comment: I’ve tried `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with `juhä` instead of `juhu` in `\juhu` and `\test`. Interestingly, it does work in expansion-only contexts (`\typeout`, `\write` to TOC).

Comment: The code assumes that the test string is already fully expanded and tests the expansion of the supplied string against that. this doesn't work for the inputenc characters in the fixed text string. It's probably more natural to have an equality test for _two_ strings and treats them equally, fully expanding both. I'll update my answer later.

Comment: Are you going to update your answer? I’m just too curious :-)

Comment: er yes, just need to find a bit of time (and I'm a year older than when I wrote that comment, mind's going you know....)

Answer (score 14):

Here a macro which compares both strings character for character and is fully expandable, therefore robust. It works fine for you test case. Note that it might fail if the input does not contain only strings. Included races for example would cause a lot of issues.

The `` \romannumeral-`0 `` trick is used to fully expand the input until at least the first character. This character is then separated and the second input is expanded and split in the same way. Both are compared and if equal the whole thing is repeated until two different characters are found or the end of both strings is reached.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\juhu}{%
  juhu%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifstreq[2]{%
    \expandafter\@ifstreq\romannumeral-`0#1\relax\@nnil\romannumeral-`0#2\relax\@nnil
}

\def\@ifstreq#1#2\@nnil#3\@nnil{%
    \expandafter\@@ifstreq#3\@nnil{#1}{#2}
}

\long\def\@afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}%

\def\@@ifstreq#1#2\@nnil#3#4{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx\relax#1\empty
            \ifx\relax#3\empty 2\else 1\fi
        \else
        \if#3#1\else 1\fi\fi
    \space
        \@afterfi{%
        \expandafter\@ifstreq\romannumeral-`0#4\@nnil\romannumeral-`0#2\@nnil}%
    \or
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
}

\makeatother


\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \ifstreq{#1}{juhu}{Juhu!}{Oje!}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\juhu}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Résumé: Works! :-) Based on `\romannumeral`. Simple active characters are handled (`~`, for instance, not in PDF strings), comparison is catcode-agnostic. But, `inputenc` characters are not handled.

Answer (score 9):

Here another fully-expandable macro which compares both strings character for character. However, here `\csname` is used to expand the strings fully *and* ensure that both have the same catcode. This is important if you compare a string against internal values like `\jobname` where the characters aren't officially letters.

Note that this approach will cause an error if any input is not fully expandable down to characters. This also excludes the use of many of not all non-English letters like German umlauts which are implemented as macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\juhu}{%
  juhu%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifstreq[2]{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \@ifstreq\expandafter\string\csname#1\expandafter
    \expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\relax
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@nnil
    \expandafter\string\csname#2\endcsname\relax\@nnil
}

\long\def\@afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\def\@ifstreq#1#2\@nnil#3#4\@nnil{%
    \ifcase0%
        \ifx\relax#1\empty
            \ifx\relax#3\empty 2\else 1\fi
        \else
        \if#3#1\else 1\fi\fi
    \space
        \@afterfi{\@ifstreq#2\@nnil#4\@nnil}%
    \or
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \fi
}

\makeatother


\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \ifstreq{#1}{juhu}{Juhu!}{Oje!}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\test{\juhu}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Résumé: Works! :-) Based on `\csname ... \endcsname`. Simple active characters are handled (`~`, for instance, not), comparison is catcode-agnostic. But, `inputenc` characters are not handled.