# Misplaced \omit and \multicolumn in \IfEqCase

Tags: tables, macros, conditionals, xstring, multicolumn

I have the following code with a command that creates rows for a tabular:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\condrow}[2]{
\IfEqCase{#1}{
 {l}{#2 & & \\}
 {r}{ & & #2 \\}
 {c}{ & #2 & \\}
 {m}{\multicolumn{3}{c}{#2} \\}
}[\PackageError{condrow}{Undefined option: #1}{}]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \condrow{l}{left}
 \condrow{r}{right}
 \condrow{c}{center}
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{manual multi} \\ % WORKS
 \condrow{m}{condrow multi} % FAILS
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

While using the `\multicolumn` directly in the tabular works, using `\multicolumn` through the command `\condrow` fails.
My guess is that `\IfEqCase` in `\condrow` prepends something to the beginning of the `\multicolumn` command, triggering the following error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan -&gt;\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.20  \condrow{m}{condrow multi}
                                 % FAILS
```

Prepending `\\` before `\multicolumn` in the command makes the error disappear, but inserts an empty row.
The problem [Misplaced \omit. \multispan with \newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69606/35877) is similar. However, the answers do not solve my case. I have tried using the `ifthen` package for branching without success.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `expl3` solution:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\condrow}{ m m }
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    { l } { #2 &    &    \\ }
    { r } {    &    & #2 \\ }
    { c } {    & #2 &    \\ }
    { m } { \multicolumn{3}{c}{#2} \\ }
   }
   { \PackageError{condrow}{Undefined~option:~#1}{<explanation>} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \condrow{l}{left}
  \condrow{r}{right}
  \condrow{c}{center}
  \condrow{m}{condrow multi}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This has the advantage of being more easily extended to accept new options.

[image]

Comment: The code gives me `! Undefined control sequence.
\condrow #1#2-&gt;\str_case:nnF 
                             {#1}{{l}{#2&&\\}{r}{&&#2\\}{c}{&#2&\\}{m}{\mult...
l.20   \condrow{l}{left}`

Comment: @faf0 Upgrade your TeX installation. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using `texlive-full` on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @faf0 Sorry, but the Ubuntu/Debian TeX distribution is really outdated.

Answer (score 6):

As Werner said you need an expandable test. As you are just comparing single letters an alternative to `\pdfstrcmp` is `\if`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\newcommand*{\condrow}[2]{%
       \if l#1 #2 & & \\%
  \else\if r#1 &  & #2 \\%
  \else\if c#1 & #2 & \\%
  \else\if m#1\multicolumn{3}{c}{#2} \\%
  \else\PackageError{condrow}{Undefined option: #1}{}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \condrow{l}{left}
  \condrow{r}{right}
  \condrow{c}{center}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{manual multi} \\ % WORKS
  \condrow{m}{condrow multi} % WORKS
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the same error as in [Misplaced `\omit`. `\multispan` with `\newcommand`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69606/5764) - it's just not that visible. The problem is that [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring)'s `\IfEqCase` is not expandable since it makes assignments to perform the comparison. Instead, using a trick from [On testing two fully expanded character strings for equality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59565/5764), you can utilize pdfTeX's `\pdfstrcmp` to compare strings in an expandable way:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\condrow}[2]{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{l}=\z@ #2 & & \\
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{r}=\z@ & & #2 \\
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{c}=\z@ & #2 & \\
  \else\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{m}=\z@ \multicolumn{3}{c}{#2} \\
  \else\PackageError{condrow}{Undefined option: #1}{}%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \condrow{l}{left}
  \condrow{r}{right}
  \condrow{c}{center}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{manual multi} \\ % WORKS
  \condrow{m}{condrow multi} % WORKS
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For information, if you use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, with its built-in command `\Block` instead of `\multicolumn`, you have directly the output you wish (because `\Block` is a protected command which works as is).

However, you need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand*{\condrow}[2]{
\IfEqCase{#1}{
 {l}{#2 & & \\}
 {r}{ & & #2 \\}
 {c}{ & #2 & \\}
 {m}{\Block{1-3}{#2} & & \\}
}[\PackageError{condrow}{Undefined option: #1}{}]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \condrow{l}{left}
 \condrow{r}{right}
 \condrow{c}{center}
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{manual multi} \\ 
 \condrow{m}{condrow multi}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]