# The \IfStrEq (from xstring package) does not work properly

Tags: xstring

I read a file line to `\a`. Say `\a` equals `A Q B` with a space before A and after B.
Then I use `\StrBetween[2,3]{\a}{ }{ }[\itstr]`, so that `\itstr` equals `Q`.
Now `\IfStrEq{\itstr}{Q}{true}{false}` should be `true`, but it is not. Would you help me with this please.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document not just inline fragments

Comment: I have an \afile whose first line is A Q B. \readline\afile to \a (\a=" A Q B ") \StrBetween[2,3]{\a}{ }{ }[\itstr] (\itstr="Q") \IfStrEq{\itstr}{Q}{True}{False}

Comment: That's not a compilable document. It's a line. A document begins with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{xstring} \begin{document}...\end{document}`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59565/on-testing-two-fully-expanded-character-strings-for-equality (But please tell me someone where can I find the question about MWE... I can never find it when need it)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\StrBetween[1,2]{\a}{\space}{\space}[\itstr]` rather, in order to catch the content between the first (1) and second (2) occurcence of the explicit space tokens in the string, so `\itstr` should expand to `Q`?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xy}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\oddsidemargin=0.5cm
\evensidemargin=0.5cm
\textwidth=16cm
\topmargin=0cm \textheight=21.6cm

\begin{document}
\newdimen\qsum
\newread\Karnameh\immediate\openin\Karnameh=Karnameh
\readline\Karnameh to \a 
\StrBetween[6,7]{ \a }{ }{ }[\itstr] itstr=$|\itstr|$
\IfStrEq{\itstr}{Q}{\global\qsum=1pt}{\global\qsum=5pt}
qsum=\the\qsum\end{document}

Comment: Karnameh is a file that contains one line, which is:StNumber LastName FirstName Dotssss D Q Q Q A A A Q A Examm A Q A A Q Q A A Examm Q Q Q A A A A Q A Q Examm Examm ExCr

Comment: I tried \space, same problem.

Comment: I used geometry package, no success. Do I need to change or enter any other parameters?

Comment: Try to change from `\readline` to `\read` and use `\space` as suggested above

Comment: @Naser: Please consider to accept my solution then.

Answer (score 6):

If letters or strings should be read and compared later with `xstring` macros `\read` should be used instead of `\readline`, the latter detokenizing (i.e. changing the catcodes to 12 for all characters except of character 32 which will get catcode 10 the content, which is not wanted here. `\read` maintains the catcodes, so characters belonging to 'letter'  will have this category later on still.

Also explicit `\space` must be used instead of empty `{}` or `{ }` in order to match the content.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xstring} 
\begin{document} 
\newdimen\qsum 
\newread\Karnameh
\immediate\openin\Karnameh=Karnameh 
\read\Karnameh to \a 
\closein\Karnameh
\StrBetween[6,7]{\a}{\space}{\space}[\itstr]% 
\fbox{\itstr}

\IfStrEq{\itstr}{Q}{\global\qsum=1pt}{\global\qsum=5pt} 

qsum=\the\qsum
\end{document}
```

Please note that `\read` will also grab the `\endlinechar` here as well, but let us ignore this for a moment.

This will give `1pt` for the `\qsum` dim register.

File `Karmaneh`

```
StNumber LastName FirstName Dotssss D Q Q Q A A A Q A Examm A Q A A Q Q A A Examm Q Q Q A A A A Q A Q Examm Examm ExCr
```

[image]

**Update**

If `\readline` is a 'must', use an explicit `\detokenize` for the `Q` character that is handled to the `\IfStrEq` macro.

```
\IfStrEq{\itstr}{\detokenize{Q}}{\global\qsum=1pt}{\global\qsum=5pt}
```